# How to change the font of text in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I want to change the text font in tkinter. How am I supposed to do that? I am new to tkinter and I don't understand. Also, I have inserted a text, is its syntax correct?

```
self.text = tk.Text(parent)
self.text.insert(tk.END, "Welcome to Emotion Detector!")
self.text.pack()
```

I have only imported tkinter as tk. nothing else. Am I supposed to import anything else?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the font for all text in the widget, or just part of the text? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

For setting the font, font size and type you can use the the tuple:

```
self.text.configure(font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
```

Syntax for text insertion is ok, but there are neater ways of doing this, depending on what you are trying to achieve, f.e. using labels (which have method .config):

```
self.label = Label(parent, text = "Some text")
self.label.config(font = ("Courier New", 14))
```